# Health bar sync with the health code script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I create an UI image with the health bar and a script for it, but when my player is attacked, the image of the health bar don't change, just in the inspector the health shows the damage change. How can I make the UI image health bar to change when player is attacked? Do I need to change something in the script?

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class HealthBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static HealthBar singleton;
    public Image currentHealthbar;
    public Text ratioText;

    public float currentHealth;
    public float maxHealth = 100f;
    public bool isDead = false;
    public bool isGameOver = false;
    public GameObject gameOverText;


    private void Awake()
    {
        singleton = this;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        UpdateHealthbar();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void UpdateHealthbar()
    {
        float ratio = currentHealth/ maxHealth;
        currentHealthbar.rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3(ratio, 1, 1);
        ratioText.text = (ratio * 100).ToString("0") + '%' ;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(currentHealth < 0)
        {
            currentHealth = 0;
        }
    }

    public void DamagePlayer(float damage)
    {
        if(currentHealth > 0)
        {
            currentHealth -= damage;
        }
        else
        {
            Dead();

            if (isGameOver && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);

            }
        }

        UpdateHealthbar();
    }

    void Dead()
    {
        currentHealth = 0;
        isDead = true;
        Debug.Log("Player is dead");

        gameOverText.SetActive(true);
        isGameOver = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your Start method, you probably want to call UpdateHealthbar _after_ setting currentHealth to maxHealth.

Comment: Why would you place your code back into a CSS snippet? Unity3D code can't run code snippets on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Eliasar People do it all the time because there's a quick and easy button in the ask-a-question UI. Just edit the markup out of the post and leave an edit reason. I use "code is not a runnable JS snippet" or similar.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems.

1. Your method `UpdateHealthBar` is not being called when the player takes damage. One solution is to call that method at the end of your `DamagePlayer` method. (Note that while `Update` will get called each frame, as currently written, `UpdateHealthBar` will not.)
2. Also, it looks like you're using two variables to track your player's health:  `hitpoint` and `currentHealth`. What's the difference between these two? Do you need both? Currently, `hitpoint` is being used in the `UpdateHealthbar` method, but `currentHealth` is decremented in the `DamagePlayer` method. You need both methods to use the same variable for the health bar to accurately reflect the player's health.

Comment: They might also be confused about `Update()`, as the template comment for Unity's `Update` is above their own.

Comment: What I should erase?

Comment: @MuraCosmetics It doesn't matter as long as you're consistent. So for example, you could easily get rid of hitpoint and maxHitpoint and replace any references to them with currentHealth and maxHealth, respectively.

Comment: I did this and it still doesn't change the health bar @inejwstine , I will update the script

Comment: @MuraCosmetics I recommend you put a log statement in your DamagePlayer and UpdateHealthbar methods to make sure they are actually getting called when they should be. (Something like Debug.Log("Health: " + currentHealth); )

Comment: I don't think I do the right change on the script , can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

### Use a `ScriptableObject` for your player health

There is a great write-up on `ScriptableObject` in [this Unity Blog](https://unity3d.com/how-to/architect-with-scriptable-objects) that describes this exact predicament. Basically, a `ScriptableObject` is an asset (and can also be instanced, created at runtime) that can be used by multiple components so that they reference the same thing. You would create this asset in your project and attach it to both the player's health script and the player's UI script. When the value is changed in one, it will reflect in the other. The added value is that you separate your concerns (and remove many use cases for singletons).